# how to count cells in excel with conditional statement?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I want to create a VBA script that can count the number of cells in two columns , for example column A and B, that have values "yes". Moreover, if one of the two cells or both in the same row have value "yes", I want the script to count only 1 time.

For example, if A2 and B2 have value "yes", it is counted 1 time. If A2 or B2 has value "yes", it is also counted 1 time.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: what about the function countif? http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx

Comment: @agusgambina as far as I concern, `countif` only can count separate column.

Comment: Is not for a separate column, in the link is written "Range: is the range of cells from which you want to count cells."

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--((A:A="yes")+(B:B="yes"))>0)*1)
```

[image]

I would not advise using whole column references with sumproduct, though, since with over a million rows in Excel 2007 and later, calculation might take a while. You may want to build range names that grow and shrink with the populated rows and use these instead of the column references.

Note that whole column references in SumProduct only work in Excel 2007 and later. For earlier versions of Excel you will need to ringfence a range.